# Initializer list braces on a struct that has an std::array member

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I have a user-defined struct called Element that has an array member. Inside the main function, I declare a vector of Elements. I've push_back an Element inside. Now the problem is that if I commented out the `Element<string, 2> el{ "foo", "bar" };` it throws me an error during compilation.

> error C2440: 'function-style-cast' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to Element<`std::string,2`>. Constructor for struct Element<`std::string,2`> is declared explicit.`

However, if the I uncomment the line, it compiles and works ok.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template<class T, std::size_t N> 
struct Element
{
  std::array<T, N> Words;
};

int main()
{
  Element<string, 2> el{ "foo", "bar" }; //do not comment out

  vector<Element<string, 2>> vec;
  vec.push_back(Element<string, 2>{"foo", "bar"});

  return 0;
}
```

Then I've also tried two push_back. The first push_back has two pairs of braces that surrounds the values, and the second line has one pair of braces. This compiles with no error. However, removing the first push_back gives me the same compile error.

```
vector<Element<string, 2>> vec;
vec.push_back(Element<string, 2>{{"foo", "bar"}});
vec.push_back(Element<string, 2>{ "foo", "bar" });
```

So what is the reason behind this? Why do I need to do this first before I can use the one pair of braces on push_back? Does the compiler deduce on how I use it?

I've read past questions related to this, but I'm not clear on how it works. I'm using C++ compiler for Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: All combinations work for me in GCC 4.8.

Comment: Same in clang 3.4 (that it works fine). `Element` does not have an explicit constructor, so an error message about the fact that the constructor is explicit is hard to explain other than as a compiler bug.

Comment: Weird. I can at least move forward with the workaround though.